# Linking error with taglib on Windows

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, taglib

I built `taglib` static libraries for Windows as follows. Gotto use mingw, not VS.

1. Check out `git clone https://github.com/taglib/taglib.git git_taglib`
2. Installed `cmake` with Win32 installer from cmake.org
3. Configure `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/C/taglib_package -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/C/MinGW4.4/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/C/MinGW4.4/bin/g++.exe -DENABLE_STATIC=ON -DENABLE_STATIC_RUNTIME=ON -DHAVE_ZLIB=0`
4. Compile `mingw32-make.exe`
5. Install `mingw32-make.exe install` to `C:\taglib_package`

In my Qt project, I am using this library like thus

.pro

```
INCLUDEPATH+="C:/taglib_package/include/taglib"
QMAKE_LIBDIR += "C:/taglib_package/lib"
LIBS+= -lz -ltag
```

.cpp

```
#include "fileref.h"
#include "taglib.h"
...
TagLib::FileRef f("Z:/Documents/sample.mp3");
TagLib::String artist = f.tag()->artist();
std::cout<< "Artist is " << artist << std::endl;
```

This leads to following link error

```
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKc'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK6TagLib7FileRef3tagEv'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x101): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib6StringD1Ev'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'
release/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2bd): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib6StringD1Ev'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\taglib_experiment.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
19:56:21: The process "C:\MinGW4.4\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project taglib_experiment (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

The code works fine on a Mac. So I suppose the culprit is the lib. How should I compile the library to solve the above linking error?

Comment: Hi @S B. I think I'm having a similar problem like the one you had [here : Linking error with taglib on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889486/linking-error-with-taglib-on-windows). Would you please mind taking a look at my question [here : How to include a library in a Qt project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672127/how-to-include-a-library-in-a-qt-project) and see if you can help? It is a [TagLib 1.11.1.](http://taglib.org/#windows) issue. It would be really helpful if you helped with some input. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-DTAGLIB_STATIC` switch when compiling *your* code

Comment: Worked for me, the library was indeed compiled in static mode thus the -DTAGLIB_STATIC was required to used it this way.