# How to include a library in a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I'm trying to create a project that uses the TagLib library. I'm not really sure of how exactly to go about it.

I have downloaded [TagLib 1.11.1](http://taglib.org/#windows).

**I built it as follows:**

*Build zlib, by first having CMake create a Visual Studio solution file, then building this solution with Visual Studio:*

> mkdir build && cd build
>   cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="e:\workspace\lib\installed"
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Debug INSTALL.vcxproj
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj

*Build TagLib much in the same way:*

> cd ....\taglib-1.11.1
>   mkdir build && cd build
>   cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="e:\workspace\lib\installed" -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="e:\workspace\lib\installed\include" -DZLIB_LIBRARY="e:\workspace\lib\installed\lib\zlib.lib" -DWITH_ASF=on -DWITH_MP4=on -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=on
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj

I create a simple Qt Console Application:

[image]

I then add **`tag.lib`** from the TagLib Build above in `E:\workspace\lib\installed\lib` using Qt

> Qt -> Add Library -> Library Type *(External Library)* -> .......

main.cpp :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <taglib/fileref.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    TagLib::FileRef f("D:/Dire Straits - Sultans of Swing.mp3");
    return a.exec();
}
```

taglibtest.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = taglibtest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltagd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltagd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds

HEADERS += \
    taglib/aifffile.h \
    taglib/aiffproperties.h \
    taglib/apefile.h \
    taglib/apefooter.h \
    taglib/apeitem.h \
    taglib/apeproperties.h \
    taglib/apetag.h \
    taglib/asfattribute.h \
    taglib/asffile.h \
    taglib/asfpicture.h \
    taglib/asfproperties.h \
    etc....
    etc....
```

I get the following errors whenever I try Building the project in Qt:

```
F:\taglibtest\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKc'  

F:\taglibtest\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE'  

F:\taglibtest\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'  

F:\taglibtest\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'  

:-1: error: release/main.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'  

:-1: error: final link failed: Invalid operation  

collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do to fix this and get working with TagLib?

taglibtest.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = taglibtest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltagd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltagd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/taglib/builds/ -ltag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/taglib/builds

HEADERS += \
    taglib/aifffile.h \
    taglib/aiffproperties.h \
    taglib/apefile.h \
    taglib/apefooter.h \
    taglib/apeitem.h \
    taglib/apeproperties.h \
    taglib/apetag.h \
    taglib/asfattribute.h \
    taglib/asffile.h \
    taglib/asfpicture.h \
    taglib/asfproperties.h \
    etc....
    etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have compiled `TagLib` and `zlib` with `Visual Studio` and you compile your project with `mingw` (at least that's what I can guess from error messages). This won't work. You need to compile all your libraries and apps with the very same compiler.

`Visual Studio` and `gcc` have different `ABI`'s so `gcc` cannot see `Visual`'s symbols.