# How to build C++ libraries for use in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, static-libraries, taglib

This question is related to this one I posted earlier : [How to include a library in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672127/how-to-include-a-library-in-a-qt-project/40673332#40673332).

I'm trying to create Qt a project that uses the [TagLib](http://taglib.org/#windows) library. I'm not really sure of how exactly to go about it.

I have downloaded [TagLib 1.11.1](http://taglib.org/#windows).

**I built it following steps in [this tutorial](https://muckingabout.eu/2014/02/08/building-taglib-on-windows/):**

*Build zlib, by first having CMake create a Visual Studio solution file, then building this solution with Visual Studio:*

> mkdir build && cd build
>   cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="e:\workspace\lib\installed"
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Debug INSTALL.vcxproj
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj

*Build TagLib much in the same way:*

> cd ....\taglib-1.11.1
>   mkdir build && cd build
>   cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="e:\workspace\lib\installed" -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="e:\workspace\lib\installed\include" -DZLIB_LIBRARY="e:\workspace\lib\installed\lib\zlib.lib" -DWITH_ASF=on -DWITH_MP4=on -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=on
>   msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj

This building procedure doesn't seem to work in a Qt project.

Could somebody please point me in the right direction as to how to build [taglib Release 1.11.1 (Windows 10)](http://taglib.org/#windows).

Something in the direction like what is [HERE](https://muckingabout.eu/2014/02/08/building-taglib-on-windows/)** could really be helpful. I'm starting up on C++ and documentation on building liblaries is really limited. It could save a lot of time, for anyone else trying to build liblaries for use on Qt.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Comment: Nope. Still trying to work it out. Please help if you can. Would be greatly appreciated @Sergey Gatich.

Comment: Please describe the problem in more details. What OS, IDE, compiler do you use? On what stage do you face the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have sources of TagLib, you can create a solution in MS VS 2015, then add a subproject that contains your Qt project and another subproject (namely DLL library) that contains TagLib. After that you can link your Qt project against TagLib:

1. Right-click on Qt project, choose `Properties`.
2. In the left panel choose `Common Properties`, `References`.
3. Choose `Add new reference` and add TagLib project.
4. Then choose `C/C++`, `General`, `Additional Include Directories`.
5. Add there relative path to TagLig headers that you use in your Qt project.

After that you can include just filenames in your Qt project without relative paths. For example:

```
#include "SomeHeaderFromTagLib.h"
```

If you have questions, feel free to ask, I'll update the post.

**UPDATE 1**
You can use Qt Creator instead of Visual Studio. Community version can be downloaded from Qt website. Documentation how to configure CMake using Qt Creator:

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html

**UPDATE 2**
Make sure that you're using corresponding Qt version. If you're dealing with MS VS 2015 C++ compiler, then you should use Qt version that is built using this and only this compiler (msvc2015 version).

**UPDATE 3**
If you're using Qt MSVC 2013 32 bit, then you should use 32 bit TagLib library. You should compile it with following option:

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 2013"
```

instead of

```
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```

Note that you should have MS VC 2013 compiler on your machine.

After you compile TagLib, open your Qt project in Qt Creator:

1. Right-click on it.
2. Choose `Add library...`
3. Choose `External`
4. Choose file of the library (.lib)

Then right-click on the whole project and choose `Run qmake`.
After that you should be able to build the project.

Comment: `Right-click on Qt project, choose Properties` -> That's not possible in Qt. There's no properties in Qt, Qt Creator 3.6.0, Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)

Comment: It concerns Microsoft Visual Studio only. I'll add UPDATE 3 to explain how to add libraries in Qt Creator.

Comment: @SergeyGatich I tried this but my program crashes using `taglib` (`Qt-Creator`)  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131512/programm-crashes-using-taglib?noredirect=1#comment70030047_41131512). I used a native `MinGW`-Installation since i could not manage to get `CMake` to work with the one included with `Qt`