# Programm crashes using Taglib

Tags: qt, taglib

I am trying to use `Taglib` with `Qt5.7`. But my programm crashes:

> The GDB process terminated unexpectedly (exit code 0).
>
> Cannot continue debugged process: The program is not being run.
>
> During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135

There did not seem to be any error messages while building Taglib.

*.pro file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = untitled2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

TAGLIBDIR = $$quote(D:/D/Programmieren/Libraries/taglib)
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote( $${TAGLIBDIR}/include )
LIBS += -L$$quote($${TAGLIBDIR}/lib) -ltag
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>    
#include <taglib/tag.h>
#include <taglib/fileref.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    TagLib::FileRef ref("D:/D/Media/Musik/Disturbed/The Sickness/Disturbed - Stupify.mp3");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Edit:
I created Taglib-buildfiles using CMake-GUI and native MinGW-Installation since I did not manage to create them using Qt. My OS is Windows 10 x64 Education and I use Qt-Creator. I downloaded the latest Taglib-Release (1.11.1)

Why I cant create buildfiles using CMake:
First some *dll-files where missing, i coud solve that by just copying the ones from native MinGW-Installation to QT-MinGW.
Second I could not find any of the *exe-files desired by CMake so i could not change the path from native MinGW-Installation.

After rebuilding Taglib in debugmode I get this errors:

> main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKc'
>
> main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE'
>
> main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK6TagLib7FileRef3tagEv'
>
> main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK6TagLib6String9toCStringEb'
>
> main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib6StringD1Ev'
>
> main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'
>
> main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib6StringD1Ev'
>
> main.cpp:10: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'
>
> collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you type `bt` in GDB you'll get a backtrace, which would be very useful in trying to figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: @scotchi Where do I have to add `bt`? I would guess in `Command line arguments` in the `Run Settings`? I cannot see any differences with the output. Also I am not sure how that could help since the program crashes during startup.

Comment: The output you pasted indicated that you're using GDB (GNU Debugger).  GDB has a console where you can type commands -- typing `bt` prints a backtrace.  This isn't a command for your program -- it's a command for GDB.

Comment: @scotchi Thank you, I found the debugging console. But I cannot type any command, since the GDB is crashing: `Can only evaluate during a debug session.`

Comment: Could you provide more details? Under what OS do you try to run taglib, what IDE do you use?

Comment: @SergeyGatich I added them.

Comment: You can choose 'Debug' mode on the right panel, then right-click on 'Breakpoints' window (right bottom), choose 'Set breakpoint', choose 'C++ exception' as exception type. Then you should run the program and see what will occur.

Comment: I added 'exception thrown' and 'exception caught'. Both breakpoints are not triggered. The only thing that I can think of is that the problem is created since I used native MinGW-installation for creating the build files. I added information why I could not use the MinGW included with Qt.

Comment: The problem can be that you use release build for Taglib library. It doesn't contain debug information such as places for breakpoints and interrupts. Can you try to rebuild Taglib in a debug mode?

Comment: And yes, if your project is in a debug mode, but the library is in a release mode, it can lead your program to a crash. That can be a cause of your problem. The modes must correspond.

Comment: I rebuild it and now I get undefined reference errors (see edit)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889486/linking-error-with-taglib-on-windows. Maybe it will solve your problem. See also: http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/, http://mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/build_windows_dependencies#taglib

Comment: Where do I have to add that 'switch'? I tried to add it as a make argument but that does not work (unvalid argument). I started with that link of joelverhagen but I got stuck at 'Setting up project' since Taglib does not seem to contain a profile anymore.

Comment: I rebuild taglib as you told in debugmode but now i checked `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` and I do not get those reference errors anymore but am still stucked at my original problem.

Comment: Have you tried to catch C++ exceptions in a debug mode?

Comment: Then I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using new version (5.8 instead of 5.7) of Qt.